# Django UpdateView allow only if object fields meet certain conditions

Tags: python, django

I want that an `Invoice` may only be changed if it falls between certain dates; these two dates are stored in the DB and indicate the currently open month (to prevent users from changing old invoices).

Where would be the best place to enforce this restriction in my `InvoiceUpdateView`?

A simple solution: add form validation (method `InvoiceForm.clean_date()`). That works, but ideally, I want the `InvoiceUpdateView` to not even show the form if the `Invoice` date is outside of the established range, it should just redirect back to the `InvoiceDetailView`.

The following code works, but it calls `.get_object()` twice: I have to call it once to get the objects date, and later this method is called again in the parents `.get()` or `.post()`.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    ... more fields ...

class InvoiceUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    permission_required = ...
    template_name = ...
    model = Invoice
    fields = ...

    def can_be_modified(self):
        # fetch from DB
        start_date = ...
        end_date = ...

        if start_date <= self.object.date <= end_date:
            return True
        return False

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if not self.can_be_modified():
            return redirect('invoice-detail')

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if not self.can_be_modified():
            return redirect('invoice-detail')

        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Does anyone have a better suggestion/approach? Or is there a good argument to just stick with simple form validation?

In case it matters: `python 3.5` with `django 1.11`

Comment: I think the easiest way to not show the update at all would be to handle it in your template and keep what you have in your view. That way if someone does somehow by pass the template the rule is still enforced on the backend

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. In my `DetailView` I hide the `update` button when the `Invoice` date is out of the established range, so a user shouldn't accidentally get to the update page (he can only get there by typing the URL directly into the address bar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up displaying the form anyways in the `InvoiceUpdateView`; instead of redirecting on `GET` request, I now only displaying a warning message together with the form. I prevent the updating of the `Invoice` instance in the `POST` requests.

```
class InvoiceUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    permission_required = ...
    template_name = ...
    model = Invoice
    fields = ...

    @cached_property
    def can_be_modified(self):
        # fetch from DB
        start_date = ...
        end_date = ...

        if start_date <= self.object.date <= end_date:
            return True
        return False

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if not self.can_be_modified:
            messages.error(self.request, 'date is not in range')
            return redirect('invoice-detail')

        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if not self.can_be_modified:
            messages.error(self.request, 'date is not in range')

        return ctx
```

Its not the most elegant solution, but it is good enough for my case.